# How can I give ScrollContentPresenter a backgroundcolor?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I created a nice working scroll/zoom/pan usercontrol, but now I realize that the `ScrollContentPresenter` has no background color that I can set.

That is, when I zoom *out* my canvas is scaled into a smaller area and between the `ScrollViewer` and the `Canvas` an area remains completely white, it is the `ScrollContentPresenter`.

Is there an easy solution?

Some code to explain this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <Grid Name="grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
         Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
         Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualHeight}">
   <Grid.LayoutTransform>
       <TransformGroup>
           <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
        </TransformGroup>
   </Grid.LayoutTransform>
       <ListBox ... />
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

With this code the `ScrollContentPresenter` becomes visible in white when zooming out. The canvas is then *centered* in it.

Without the `Width` & `Height` binidng of `Grid` in the code the `ScrollContentPresenter` remains invisible when zooming out. The canvas is then fixed in the top-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably would need to set the `Background` on whatever the Parent of the `ScrollContentPresenter` is (the `Grid` or `Canvas` or whatever that contains the `ScrollContentPresenter`).

Comment: Looks plausible,but not the Grid in my code, but an internal Grid of ScrollViewer is the villain.

Comment: Ok: `var grid = Tools.FindChildVisualTree<Grid>(scrollViewer);
grid.Background = Brushes.Red;`