# How can I set ScrollContentPresenter a backgroundcolor?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

[How can I give ScrollContentPresenter a backgroundcolor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253991/how-can-i-give-scrollcontentpresenter-a-backgroundcolor/22254199#22254199) is the same question, but I set the `Background` on the Parent of the `ScrollContentPresenter`. It is the `Grid` and it does not work for me. I can not change the background.

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{Binding L1, Source={x:Static color:DesignBrushCollection.DesignColors}}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Background="Red">
                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0"  Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" 
                                           Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  TargetName="border"
                                        Value="{Binding AC3, Source={x:Static color:DesignBrushCollection.DesignColors}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger  Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  TargetName="border"
                                        Value="{Binding AC3, Source={x:Static color:DesignBrushCollection.DesignColors}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border"
                                        Value="{Binding BG1, Source={x:Static color:DesignBrushCollection.DesignColors}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger  Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Width="auto" Height="auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:CommonLabel  RequiredMark="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type local:CommonComboBox}},Path=RequiredMark}"  
                                FontSize="13" Padding="0" 
                                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type local:CommonComboBox}},Path=Content}"
                                Grid.Row="0" Height="16" Width="139" 
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <ScrollViewer  Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBox x:Name="TextField" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" CaretBrush="{Binding AC3, Source={x:Static color:DesignBrushCollection.DesignColors}}"
                     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CommonTextField}},Path=Content,Mode=OneWay}" >
            </TextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Tested with `ListBox`, style was set implicitly in `ListBox.Resources`, background was red. Is it that, what you have wanted??

Comment: i tested with textbox,can not change the color, i added the applied source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBox.Background` does override the `ScrollViewer.Background`. If you set `TextBox.Background = "Transparent"` or `TextBox.Background = "{x:Null}"` you will see `ScrollViewer.Background`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextField" Background="Transparent" ... />
```

Be aware, that `ScrollViewer.IsFocused` set to true if you click the border of `ScrollViewer` or set the focus in code behind, not if you input a text in the `TextBox`.

Comment: so kind of you,thanks. it is helpful. about the advice how can i change the background when input ,<grid> or <ScrollContentPresenter> dont have Template.

Comment: From link: _"Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well"_. If the posted answer doesn't answer your question, then undo it.